# No runnable methods on JUnit test class (netbeans)

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans-7, junit4, runnable

Help me please!

I have created an `EmployeeTest` class to write to an `Employee` class but this error occurs before I can finish it.  I had written the similar project before this project, it ran without errors. This is a very simple class as you can see below.

This is the error message:

```
initialization ERROR : No runnable methods
    -No runnable methods
    -java.lang.Exception
    -at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

This is `EmployeeTest` class:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class EmployeeTest {
Employee employee;
public EmployeeTest() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    employee = new Employee("Austin", "Powers", 70000.00); 
}
public void testGetName(){
    String expected = "Austin Powers";
    String actual = employee.getName();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);


}
public void testGetSalary(){
    double expected = 70000.00;
    double actual = employee.getSalary();
    double marginOfError = 0.0001;
    assertEquals(expected, actual, marginOfError);
 }
public void testChangeSalary(){

    double percentIncrease = 5.00;
    employee.changeSalary(percentIncrease);
    double expected = 73500.00;
    double actual = employee.getSalary();
    double marginOfError = 0.0001;
    assertEquals(expected, actual, marginOfError);
  }
}
```

This is unfinished `Employee` class:

```
class Employee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double salary;

public Employee(String austin, String powers, double d) {
    firstName = austin;
    lastName = powers;

}


String getName() {
    return firstName +" "+lastName;
      }

double getSalary() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

void changeSalary(double percentIncrease) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add annotations to your test methods as follows:

```
@Test
public void testGetSalary(){
```

Unlike Junit 3, JUnit 4 relies on annotations, not method names to identify tests.

Comment: It 's really work. Thank you very much, I will remember this :)